# Yellow vertical line in YouTube video timeline

Tags: youtube

What does the yellow vertical line signify in the YouTube video timeline?

Is it an ad start point, or is it its you-can-play-now point as many believe?

It's not clickable nor does hovering over it do anything special. What it is there for?

#### References:

- [What is the little, yellow, vertical line that is under the progress bar?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=1209256fb0e4e65c&hl=en)
- [What about the yellow line in the timeline in videos?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=7bf581a2d27370da&hl=en)

Comment: Anyone know _why_ they are there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It marks the point when an ad pops up in the player.

Here is the marker visible in a video:

[image: YouTube - Yellow Marker No Ad]

And here is the popup advert when the player reaches the marker:

[image: YouTube - Yellow Marker Popup Ad visible]