# What does the vertical lines mean in a YouTube video timeline?

Tags: youtube

I'm **not** talking about the [yellow lines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16895/yellow-vertical-line-in-youtube-video-timeline). I'm talking about the ones highlighted in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of the YouTube video player]

And also, why are they different in size?

Comment: Can you link to a video or videos demonstrating this?

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9J8ifuHyHjk) but you can see this similarity into any big video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a time stamp. They only appear on long videos. The smaller lines signifies a minute, the bigger (deeper) an hour. They make it easier to jump to a specific point in the video.

Comment: That matches up to the link provided in the comment. Anybody have a canonical source, beyond our observations?